# Is it bad practice for a case to have multiple breaks?

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement

This is a super dumbed down version of what I am doing, but imagine needing to perform multiple validations on an object within a switch statement. At any point in the validation we may decide that we do not want to continue working with the object.

The dumb example:

```
var yummies = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 3},
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 4}
];

var purchases = [];

for (var i = 0; i < yummies.length; i++) {
  var yummy = yummies[i];
  switch (yummy.name) {
      case 'apples':
        if (purchases.indexOf(yummy.name) > -1) {
          break;
        }

        //A ton of other code including, possibly other breaks

        purchases.push(yummy.name);
        break;
  }
}
```

A `return` won't work as I still want to continue through the loop. I think I could go with a `continue` statement could work, but it looks really off seeing a `continue` in a `switch/case`.

Anyways, two `break`s in a single `case`. Any reason not to do it?

Comment: `continue` and `break` are only equivalent if the `switch` is the last statement in the loop.

Comment: You could use `if/else` instead of `break` in the middle. This is all just personal style preference.

Comment: These cases are huge. I don't really want so many `if/else` statements. Interesting about the `continue`!

Comment: You could just invert the condition in the function and place `purchases.push` inside, that way it has a single `break` after the `if(){}`

Comment: This is similar to a question that was asked yesterday about `return` statements in functions. And the general idea is the same: if you don't like deeply nested control structures, using multiple `return` or `break` can make the code easier to follow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773065/should-we-use-early-return-for-a-simple-function

Answer (score 6):

This of course is just an opinion, but I don't think it's bad per se. However, nested cases, ifs and other control structures don't make your code very readable. In situations like this, you might consider moving pieces of code to separate functions.

So your code could look like this:

```
function purchaseApple(yummyName) {
  if (purchases.indexOf(yummyName) == -1) {
    purchases.push(yummyName);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < yummies.length; i++) {
  var yummy = yummies[i];
  switch (yummy.name) {
      case 'apples':
        purchaseApples(yummy.name);
        break;
  }
}
```

Or maybe even move the condition to the function too:

```
function tryPurchaseApple(yummyName) {
  if (yummyName == 'apples' && purchases.indexOf(yummyName) == -1) {
    purchases.push(yummyName);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < yummies.length; i++) {
  var yummy = yummies[i];
  tryPurchaseApple(yummy.name);
  tryPurchasePears(yummy.name);
}
```

These are just suggestions, of course. It's hard to make a sensible example out of this situation, no offence. ;)

Comment: Good call about moving the code to multiple functions. I am a little constrained with the project to creating private methods, unfortunately; otherwise I would definitely go that route.

Comment: why did you decide to not use early return in the `purchaseApple()` function?

Comment: @Toskan Well, this answer is 8 years old, so I don't remember exactly, but I don't think it would improve much. You'd still need the condition, and then have 3 lines of code instead of 2. But also it wasn't really relevant for the example, I think.